# Not able to query on local key-value store(Kafka-Stream)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on the use-case where I need to query KTable(Using local key-value stores approach).My sample data which is present inside the topic:

```
A,Blue
A,Blue 
A,Yellow
A,Red
A,Yellow
A,Yellow
B,Blue
C,Red
C,Red
B,Blue
```

Based On Input I want to generate the output and store in the topic:

```
A Blue:2,Yellow:3,Red:1
B Blue:2
C Red:2
```

Approach:
1) I first performed count operation by reading topic data in Kstream.

```
     //set the properties for interactive queries
     props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG,"localhost:9092" );
        props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "D:\\Kafka_data\\Local_store");

 //read the user input from Kafka topic: data
        final KStream<String,String> userDataSource = builder.stream("data");

        final KGroupedStream<String,String> inputData = userDataSource.
                map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.split(",")[0].toString() +  "_"+ value.split(",")[1].toString() , value.split(",")[1].toString()) )
                .selectKey((s, s2) -> s)
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()));


        final KTable<String,Long> inputAggregationResult  = inputData.count();
```

Result of the above code:

```
A_Blue 1
A_Yellow 1
A_Red 1
A_Yellow 2
A_Yellow 3
B_Blue 1
C_Red 1
C_Red 2
B_Blue 2
```

2) Then store the result in topic:

```
inputAggregationResult.toStream().to("input-data-aggregation", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

3) Now reading data from the topic(input-data-aggregation) as Ktable so that I can query.

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KTable<String, Object> ktableInformation = builder.table("input-data-aggregation", Materialized.<String, Object, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("CountsValueStore"));

 final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);

streams.cleanUp();
 streams.start();

 ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Object> keyValueStore;
        Map<String,Object> information = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
        while (true) {
            try {

                // Get the key-value store CountsKeyValueStore
                 keyValueStore =
                        streams.store(ktableInformation.queryableStoreName(), QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());


                //read the value
                KeyValueIterator<String, Object> range = keyValueStore.range("all", "streams");
                while (range.hasNext()) {
                    KeyValue<String, Object> next = range.next();
                    information.put(next.key,next.value);
                    System.out.println("count for " + next.key + ": " + next.value);
                }
                // close the iterator to release resources
                range.close();


            } catch (InvalidStateStoreException ignored) {
                ignored.printStackTrace();


            }
        }
```

4)When I am trying to query data it is giving empty data(No output is getting print).

Can someone guide me if I missed any step as part Querying local key-value stores? or any other alternative to achieve the target output. I have verified that Kafka is writing Local Key-value store data inside my local instance but while reading(Querying) data it's giving an empty result.

Comment: Why do you not query `inputAggregationResult` directly? Also, is the store name correct? Do you get exceptions? Do you run multiple instances (ie, do you query the right shard)?

Comment: I am using a single instance of Kafka(Running in windows) with one broker. I want to store the inputAggregationResult into the java object for further processing. I found only the ReadOnlyKeyValueStore approach to store information from the KTable.Is their other alertnative to fetch information from the Ktable?

Comment: I did not ask about the number of broker, but the number of application instances. -- Can you check the lag of your application? Maybe you need to use the rest-tool to reset your offsets?

Comment: Sure. I will try to use rest-tool to reset offset and run the application again. I will update the observation after these changes.